# Unable to build Docker images through Jenkins installed on Kubernetes

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, kubernetes-helm

I used the following helm chart to install Jenkins

https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/jenkinsci/jenkins

The problem is it does't build docker images, saying there's no docker. Docker was installed on host with `sudo apt install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io`

```
var/jenkins_home/workspace/test@tmp/durable-23187d38/script.sh: 2: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test@tmp/durable-23187d38/script.sh: docker: not found
```

There was also another error

```
Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker": error=2, No such file or directory
```

I tried experimenting with multiple values.yaml variations with no luck.

Here's the latest one(I removed the ingress part). There might be redundant parts like that `podTemplates:` with docker config(copied it from some github repo) and `agent: volumes:` where I mount the same thing `/var/run/docker.sock` I don't understand where it should go.

I'm using k3s if it matters. And this is just a plain VPS.

```yaml
# Default values for jenkins.
# This is a YAML-formatted file.
# Declare name/value pairs to be passed into your templates.
# name: value

## Overrides for generated resource names
# See templates/_helpers.tpl
# nameOverride:
# fullnameOverride:
# namespaceOverride:

# For FQDN resolving of the controller service. Change this value to match your existing configuration.
# ref: https://github.com/kubernetes/dns/blob/master/docs/specification.md
clusterZone: "cluster.local"

renderHelmLabels: true

controller:
  # Used for label app.kubernetes.io/component
  componentName: "jenkins-controller"
  image: "jenkins/jenkins"
  tag: "2.277.2-jdk11"
  imagePullPolicy: "Always"
  imagePullSecretName:
  # Optionally configure lifetime for controller-container
  lifecycle:
  #  postStart:
  #    exec:
  #      command:
  #      - "uname"
  #      - "-a"
  disableRememberMe: false
  numExecutors: 1
  # configures the executor mode of the Jenkins node. Possible values are: NORMAL or EXCLUSIVE
  executorMode: "NORMAL"
  # This is ignored if enableRawHtmlMarkupFormatter is true
  markupFormatter: plainText
  customJenkinsLabels: []
  # The default configuration uses this secret to configure an admin user
  # If you don't need that user or use a different security realm then you can disable it
  adminSecret: true

  hostNetworking: false
  # When enabling LDAP or another non-Jenkins identity source, the built-in admin account will no longer exist.
  # If you disable the non-Jenkins identity store and instead use the Jenkins internal one,
  # you should revert controller.adminUser to your preferred admin user:
  adminUser: "admin"
  # adminPassword: <defaults to random>
  admin:
    existingSecret: ""
    userKey: jenkins-admin-user
    passwordKey: jenkins-admin-password
  # This values should not be changed unless you use your custom image of jenkins or any devired from. If you want to use
  # Cloudbees Jenkins Distribution docker, you should set jenkinsHome: "/var/cloudbees-jenkins-distribution"
  jenkinsHome: "/var/jenkins_home"
  # This values should not be changed unless you use your custom image of jenkins or any devired from. If you want to use
  # Cloudbees Jenkins Distribution docker, you should set jenkinsRef: "/usr/share/cloudbees-jenkins-distribution/ref"
  jenkinsRef: "/usr/share/jenkins/ref"
  # Path to the jenkins war file which is used by jenkins-plugin-cli.
  jenkinsWar: "/usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war"
  resources:
    # requests:
    #   cpu: "50m"
    #   memory: "256Mi"
    limits:
      cpu: "2000m"
      memory: "2048Mi"
  # Environment variables that get added to the init container (useful for e.g. http_proxy)
  # initContainerEnv:
  #   - name: http_proxy
  #     value: "http://192.168.64.1:3128"
  # containerEnv:
  #   - name: http_proxy
  #     value: "http://192.168.64.1:3128"
  # Set min/max heap here if needed with:
  # javaOpts: "-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
  # jenkinsOpts: ""
  # If you are using the ingress definitions provided by this chart via the `controller.ingress` block the configured hostname will be the ingress hostname starting with `https://` or `http://` depending on the `tls` configuration.
  # The Protocol can be overwritten by specifying `controller.jenkinsUrlProtocol`.
  # jenkinsUrlProtocol: "https"
  # If you are not using the provided ingress you can specify `controller.jenkinsUrl` to change the url definition.
  # jenkinsUrl: ""
  # If you set this prefix and use ingress controller then you might want to set the ingress path below
  # jenkinsUriPrefix: "/jenkins"
  # Enable pod security context (must be `true` if podSecurityContextOverride, runAsUser or fsGroup are set)
  usePodSecurityContext: true
  # Note that `runAsUser`, `fsGroup`, and `securityContextCapabilities` are
  # being deprecated and replaced by `podSecurityContextOverride`.
  # Set runAsUser to 1000 to let Jenkins run as non-root user 'jenkins' which exists in 'jenkins/jenkins' docker image.
  # When setting runAsUser to a different value than 0 also set fsGroup to the same value:
  runAsUser: 1000
  fsGroup: 1000
  # If you have PodSecurityPolicies that require dropping of capabilities as suggested by CIS K8s benchmark, put them here
  securityContextCapabilities: {}
  #  drop:
  #    - NET_RAW
  # Completely overwrites the contents of the `securityContext`, ignoring the
  # values provided for the deprecated fields: `runAsUser`, `fsGroup`, and
  # `securityContextCapabilities`.  In the case of mounting an ext4 filesystem,
  # it might be desirable to use `supplementalGroups` instead of `fsGroup` in
  # the `securityContext` block: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/67014#issuecomment-589915496
  # podSecurityContextOverride:
  #   runAsUser: 1000
  #   runAsNonRoot: true
  #   supplementalGroups: [1000]
  #   # capabilities: {}
  servicePort: 8080
  targetPort: 8080
  # For minikube, set this to NodePort, elsewhere use LoadBalancer
  # Use ClusterIP if your setup includes ingress controller
  serviceType: ClusterIP
  # Jenkins controller service annotations
  serviceAnnotations: {}
  # Jenkins controller custom labels
  statefulSetLabels: {}
  #   foo: bar
  #   bar: foo
  # Jenkins controller service labels
  serviceLabels: {}
  #   service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: https
  # Put labels on Jenkins controller pod
  podLabels: {}
  # Used to create Ingress record (should used with ServiceType: ClusterIP)
  # nodePort: <to set explicitly, choose port between 30000-32767
  # Enable Kubernetes Liveness and Readiness Probes
  # if Startup Probe is supported, enable it too
  # ~ 2 minutes to allow Jenkins to restart when upgrading plugins. Set ReadinessTimeout to be shorter than LivenessTimeout.
  healthProbes: true
  probes:
    startupProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: '{{ default "" .Values.controller.jenkinsUriPrefix }}/login'
        port: http
      periodSeconds: 10
      timeoutSeconds: 5
      failureThreshold: 12
    livenessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 5
      httpGet:
        path: '{{ default "" .Values.controller.jenkinsUriPrefix }}/login'
        port: http
      periodSeconds: 10
      timeoutSeconds: 5
      # If Startup Probe is not supported on your Kubernetes cluster, you might want to use "initialDelaySeconds" instead.
      # It delays the initial liveness probe while Jenkins is starting
      # initialDelaySeconds: 60
    readinessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 3
      httpGet:
        path: '{{ default "" .Values.controller.jenkinsUriPrefix }}/login'
        port: http
      periodSeconds: 10
      timeoutSeconds: 5
      # If Startup Probe is not supported on your Kubernetes cluster, you might want to use "initialDelaySeconds" instead.
      # It delays the initial readyness probe while Jenkins is starting
      # initialDelaySeconds: 60
  agentListenerPort: 50000
  agentListenerHostPort:
  agentListenerNodePort:
  disabledAgentProtocols:
    - JNLP-connect
    - JNLP2-connect
  csrf:
    defaultCrumbIssuer:
      enabled: true
      proxyCompatability: true
  # Kubernetes service type for the JNLP agent service
  # agentListenerServiceType is the Kubernetes Service type for the JNLP agent service,
  # either 'LoadBalancer', 'NodePort', or 'ClusterIP'
  # Note if you set this to 'LoadBalancer', you *must* define annotations to secure it. By default
  # this will be an external load balancer and allowing inbound 0.0.0.0/0, a HUGE
  # security risk:  https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/issues/1341
  agentListenerServiceType: "ClusterIP"
  # Optionally assign an IP to the LoadBalancer agentListenerService LoadBalancer
  # GKE users: only regional static IPs will work for Service Load balancer.
  agentListenerLoadBalancerIP:
  agentListenerServiceAnnotations: {}

  # Example of 'LoadBalancer' type of agent listener with annotations securing it
  # agentListenerServiceType: LoadBalancer
  # agentListenerServiceAnnotations:
  #   service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "True"
  #   service.beta.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-source-ranges: "172.0.0.0/8, 10.0.0.0/8"

  # LoadBalancerSourcesRange is a list of allowed CIDR values, which are combined with ServicePort to
  # set allowed inbound rules on the security group assigned to the controller load balancer
  loadBalancerSourceRanges:
  - 0.0.0.0/0
  # Optionally assign a known public LB IP
  # loadBalancerIP: 1.2.3.4
  # Optionally configure a JMX port
  # requires additional javaOpts, ie
  # javaOpts: >
  #   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=4000
  #   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
  #   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
  # jmxPort: 4000
  # Optionally configure other ports to expose in the controller container
  extraPorts: []
  # - name: BuildInfoProxy
  #   port: 9000

  # List of plugins to be install during Jenkins controller start
  # installPlugins:
  #   - kubernetes:latest
  #   - kubernetes-credentials-provider:latest
  #   - workflow-aggregator:2.6
  #   - git:latest
  #   - configuration-as-code:1.47

  # Set to false to download the minimum required version of all dependencies.
  installLatestPlugins: false

  # List of plugins to install in addition to those listed in controller.installPlugins
  additionalPlugins: []

  # Enable to initialize the Jenkins controller only once on initial installation.
  # Without this, whenever the controller gets restarted (Evicted, etc.) it will fetch plugin updates which has the potential to cause breakage.
  # Note that for this to work, `persistence.enabled` needs to be set to `true`
  initializeOnce: false

  # Enable to always override the installed plugins with the values of 'controller.installPlugins' on upgrade or redeployment.
  # overwritePlugins: true

  # Configures if plugins bundled with `controller.image` should be overwritten with the values of 'controller.installPlugins' on upgrade or redeployment.
  overwritePluginsFromImage: true

  # Enable HTML parsing using OWASP Markup Formatter Plugin (antisamy-markup-formatter), useful with ghprb plugin.
  # The plugin is not installed by default, please update controller.installPlugins.
  enableRawHtmlMarkupFormatter: false
  # Used to approve a list of groovy functions in pipelines used the script-security plugin. Can be viewed under /scriptApproval
  scriptApproval: []
  #  - "method groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic parseText java.lang.String"
  #  - "new groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic"
  # List of groovy init scripts to be executed during Jenkins controller start
  initScripts: []
  #  - |
  #    print 'adding global pipeline libraries, register properties, bootstrap jobs...'

  additionalSecrets: []
  #  - name: nameOfSecret
  #    value: secretText

  # Below is the implementation of Jenkins Configuration as Code.  Add a key under configScripts for each configuration area,
  # where each corresponds to a plugin or section of the UI.  Each key (prior to | character) is just a label, and can be any value.
  # Keys are only used to give the section a meaningful name.  The only restriction is they may only contain RFC 1123 \ DNS label
  # characters: lowercase letters, numbers, and hyphens.  The keys become the name of a configuration yaml file on the controller in
  # /var/jenkins_home/casc_configs (by default) and will be processed by the Configuration as Code Plugin.  The lines after each |
  # become the content of the configuration yaml file.  The first line after this is a JCasC root element, eg jenkins, credentials,
  # etc.  Best reference is https://<jenkins_url>/configuration-as-code/reference.  The example below creates a welcome message:
  JCasC:
    defaultConfig: true
    configScripts: {}
    #  welcome-message: |
    #    jenkins:
    #      systemMessage: Welcome to our CI\CD server.  This Jenkins is configured and managed 'as code'.
    # Ignored if securityRealm is defined in controller.JCasC.configScripts and
    # ignored if controller.enableXmlConfig=true as controller.securityRealm takes precedence
    securityRealm: |-
      local:
        allowsSignup: false
        enableCaptcha: false
        users:
        - id: "${chart-admin-username}"
          name: "Jenkins Admin"
          password: "${chart-admin-password}"
    # Ignored if authorizationStrategy is defined in controller.JCasC.configScripts
    authorizationStrategy: |-
      loggedInUsersCanDoAnything:
        allowAnonymousRead: false
  # Optionally specify additional init-containers
  customInitContainers: []
  # - name: custom-init
  #   image: "alpine:3.7"
  #   imagePullPolicy: Always
  #   command: [ "uname", "-a" ]

  sidecars:
    configAutoReload:
      # If enabled: true, Jenkins Configuration as Code will be reloaded on-the-fly without a reboot.  If false or not-specified,
      # jcasc changes will cause a reboot and will only be applied at the subsequent start-up.  Auto-reload uses the
      # http://<jenkins_url>/reload-configuration-as-code endpoint to reapply config when changes to the configScripts are detected.
      enabled: true
      image: kiwigrid/k8s-sidecar:0.1.275
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      resources: {}
        #   limits:
        #     cpu: 100m
        #     memory: 100Mi
        #   requests:
        #     cpu: 50m
        #     memory: 50Mi
      # How many connection-related errors to retry on
      reqRetryConnect: 10
      # env:
      #   - name: REQ_TIMEOUT
      #     value: "30"
      # SSH port value can be set to any unused TCP port.  The default, 1044, is a non-standard SSH port that has been chosen at random.
      # Is only used to reload jcasc config from the sidecar container running in the Jenkins controller pod.
      # This TCP port will not be open in the pod (unless you specifically configure this), so Jenkins will not be
      # accessible via SSH from outside of the pod.  Note if you use non-root pod privileges (runAsUser & fsGroup),
      # this must be > 1024:
      sshTcpPort: 1044
      # folder in the pod that should hold the collected dashboards:
      folder: "/var/jenkins_home/casc_configs"
      # If specified, the sidecar will search for JCasC config-maps inside this namespace.
      # Otherwise the namespace in which the sidecar is running will be used.
      # It's also possible to specify ALL to search in all namespaces:
      # searchNamespace:

    # Allows you to inject additional/other sidecars
    other: []
    ## The example below runs the client for https://smee.io as sidecar container next to Jenkins,
    ## that allows to trigger build behind a secure firewall.
    ## https://jenkins.io/blog/2019/01/07/webhook-firewalls/#triggering-builds-with-webhooks-behind-a-secure-firewall
    ##
    ## Note: To use it you should go to https://smee.io/new and update the url to the generete one.
    # - name: smee
    #   image: docker.io/twalter/smee-client:1.0.2
    #   args: ["--port", "{{ .Values.controller.servicePort }}", "--path", "/github-webhook/", "--url", "https://smee.io/new"]
    #   resources:
    #     limits:
    #       cpu: 50m
    #       memory: 128Mi
    #     requests:
    #       cpu: 10m
    #       memory: 32Mi
  # Name of the Kubernetes scheduler to use
  schedulerName: ""
  # Node labels and tolerations for pod assignment
  # ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector
  # ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#taints-and-tolerations-beta-feature
  nodeSelector: {}

  terminationGracePeriodSeconds:

  tolerations: []

  affinity: {}
  # Leverage a priorityClass to ensure your pods survive resource shortages
  # ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/pod-priority-preemption/
  priorityClassName:

  podAnnotations: {}
  # Add StatefulSet annotations
  statefulSetAnnotations: {}

  # StatefulSet updateStrategy
  # ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#update-strategies
  updateStrategy: {}

  ingress:


    # configures the hostname e.g. jenkins.example.com
    tls:
      - hosts:
        - "jen.kirqe.be"
        secretName: jen-kirqe-be-tls

  # Can be used to disable rendering controller test resources when using helm template
  testEnabled: true

agent:
  enabled: true
  defaultsProviderTemplate: ""
  # URL for connecting to the Jenkins contoller
  jenkinsUrl:
  # connect to the specified host and port, instead of connecting directly to the Jenkins controller
  jenkinsTunnel:
  kubernetesConnectTimeout: 5
  kubernetesReadTimeout: 15
  maxRequestsPerHostStr: "32"
  namespace: jenkins
  image: "jenkins/inbound-agent"
  tag: "4.6-1"
  workingDir: "/home/jenkins"
  customJenkinsLabels: []
  # name of the secret to be used for image pulling
  imagePullSecretName:
  componentName: "jenkins-agent"
  websocket: false
  privileged: false
  runAsUser:
  runAsGroup:
  resources:
    requests:
      cpu: "512m"
      memory: "512Mi"
    limits:
      cpu: "512m"
      memory: "512Mi"
  # You may want to change this to true while testing a new image
  alwaysPullImage: false
  # Controls how agent pods are retained after the Jenkins build completes
  # Possible values: Always, Never, OnFailure
  podRetention: "Never"
  # You can define the volumes that you want to mount for this container
  # Allowed types are: ConfigMap, EmptyDir, HostPath, Nfs, PVC, Secret
  # Configure the attributes as they appear in the corresponding Java class for that type
  # https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin/tree/master/src/main/java/org/csanchez/jenkins/plugins/kubernetes/volumes
  volumes:
  # - type: ConfigMap
  #   configMapName: myconfigmap
  #   mountPath: /var/myapp/myconfigmap
  # - type: EmptyDir
  #   mountPath: /var/myapp/myemptydir
  #   memory: false
    - type: HostPath
      hostPath: /var/run/docker.sock
      mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
  # - type: Nfs
  #   mountPath: /var/myapp/mynfs
  #   readOnly: false
  #   serverAddress: "192.0.2.0"
  #   serverPath: /var/lib/containers
  # - type: PVC
  #   claimName: mypvc
  #   mountPath: /var/myapp/mypvc
  #   readOnly: false
  # - type: Secret
  #   defaultMode: "600"
  #   mountPath: /var/myapp/mysecret
  #   secretName: mysecret
  # Pod-wide environment, these vars are visible to any container in the agent pod

  # You can define the workspaceVolume that you want to mount for this container
  # Allowed types are: DynamicPVC, EmptyDir, HostPath, Nfs, PVC
  # Configure the attributes as they appear in the corresponding Java class for that type
  # https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin/tree/master/src/main/java/org/csanchez/jenkins/plugins/kubernetes/volumes/workspace
  workspaceVolume: {}
  # - type: DynamicPVC
  #   configMapName: myconfigmap
  # - type: EmptyDir
  #   memory: false
  # - type: HostPath
  #   hostPath: /var/lib/containers
  # - type: Nfs
  #   readOnly: false
  #   serverAddress: "192.0.2.0"
  #   serverPath: /var/lib/containers
  # - type: PVC
  #   claimName: mypvc
  #   readOnly: false
  # Pod-wide environment, these vars are visible to any container in the agent pod
  envVars: []
  # - name: PATH
  #   value: /usr/local/bin
  nodeSelector: {}
  # Key Value selectors. Ex:
  # jenkins-agent: v1

  # Executed command when side container gets started
  command:
  args: "${computer.jnlpmac} ${computer.name}"
  # Side container name
  sideContainerName: "jnlp"
  # Doesn't allocate pseudo TTY by default
  TTYEnabled: false
  # Max number of spawned agent
  containerCap: 10
  # Pod name
  podName: "default"
  # Allows the Pod to remain active for reuse until the configured number of
  # minutes has passed since the last step was executed on it.
  idleMinutes: 0
  # Raw yaml template for the Pod. For example this allows usage of toleration for agent pods.
  # https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin#using-yaml-to-define-pod-templates
  # https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/
  yamlTemplate: ""
  # yamlTemplate: |-
  #   apiVersion: v1
  #   kind: Pod
  #   spec:
  #     tolerations:
  #     - key: "key"
  #       operator: "Equal"
  #       value: "value"
  # Defines how the raw yaml field gets merged with yaml definitions from inherited pod templates: merge or override
  yamlMergeStrategy: "override"
  # Timeout in seconds for an agent to be online
  connectTimeout: 100
  # Annotations to apply to the pod.
  annotations: {}

  # Below is the implementation of custom pod templates for the default configured kubernetes cloud.
  # Add a key under podTemplates for each pod template. Each key (prior to | character) is just a label, and can be any value.
  # Keys are only used to give the pod template a meaningful name.  The only restriction is they may only contain RFC 1123 \ DNS label
  # characters: lowercase letters, numbers, and hyphens. Each pod template can contain multiple containers.
  # For this pod templates configuration to be loaded the following values must be set:
  # controller.JCasC.defaultConfig: true
  # Best reference is https://<jenkins_url>/configuration-as-code/reference#Cloud-kubernetes. The example below creates a python pod template.
  podTemplates: 
    docker: |
      - name: docker
        label: docker
        containers:
          - name: docker
            image: docker:latest
            command: "/bin/sh -c"
            args: "cat"
            ttyEnabled: true
            privileged: true
            resourceRequestCpu: "400m"
            resourceRequestMemory: "512Mi"
            resourceLimitCpu: "1"
            resourceLimitMemory: "1024Mi"
        volumes:
          - hostPathVolume:
              hostPath: /var/run/docker.sock
              mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
          - hostPathVolume:
              hostPath: /data
              mountPath: /data  

# Here you can add additional agents
# They inherit all values from `agent` so you only need to specify values which differ
additionalAgents: {}
#  maven:
#    podName: maven
#    customJenkinsLabels: maven
#    # An example of overriding the jnlp container
#    # sideContainerName: jnlp
#    image: jenkins/jnlp-agent-maven
#    tag: latest
#  python:
#    podName: python
#    customJenkinsLabels: python
#    sideContainerName: python
#    image: python
#    tag: "3"
#    command: "/bin/sh -c"
#    args: "cat"
#    TTYEnabled: true

persistence:
  enabled: true
  ## A manually managed Persistent Volume and Claim
  ## Requires persistence.enabled: true
  ## If defined, PVC must be created manually before volume will be bound
  existingClaim: 
  ## jenkins data Persistent Volume Storage Class
  ## If defined, storageClassName: <storageClass>
  ## If set to "-", storageClassName: "", which disables dynamic provisioning
  ## If undefined (the default) or set to null, no storageClassName spec is
  ##   set, choosing the default provisioner.  (gp2 on AWS, standard on
  ##   GKE, AWS & OpenStack)
  ##
  storageClass:
  annotations: {}
  accessMode: "ReadWriteOnce"
  size: "5Gi"
  volumes:
  #   - name: jenkins
  #     persistentVolumeClaim:
  #       claimName: jenkins-claim
  mounts:
  #   - name: jenkins
  #     mountPath: /var/jenkins_home
    

  # volumes:
  # #  - name: nothing
  # #    emptyDir: {}
  # mounts:
  # #  - mountPath: /var/nothing
  # #    name: nothing
  # #    readOnly: true

networkPolicy:
  # Enable creation of NetworkPolicy resources.
  enabled: false
  # For Kubernetes v1.4, v1.5 and v1.6, use 'extensions/v1beta1'
  # For Kubernetes v1.7, use 'networking.k8s.io/v1'
  apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
  # You can allow agents to connect from both within the cluster (from within specific/all namespaces) AND/OR from a given external IP range
  internalAgents:
    allowed: true
    podLabels: {}
    namespaceLabels: {}
      # project: myproject
  externalAgents: {}
  #   ipCIDR: 172.17.0.0/16
  #   except:
  #     - 172.17.1.0/24

## Install Default RBAC roles and bindings
rbac:
  create: true
  readSecrets: false

serviceAccount:
  create: true
  # The name of the service account is autogenerated by default
  name:
  annotations: {}
  imagePullSecretName:


serviceAccountAgent:
  # Specifies whether a ServiceAccount should be created
  create: false
  # The name of the ServiceAccount to use.
  # If not set and create is true, a name is generated using the fullname template
  name:
  annotations: {}
  imagePullSecretName:

checkDeprecation: true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running Jenkins itself as a container. Therefore the docker command line application must be present in the container, not the host.

Easiest solution: Use a Jenkins docker image that contains the docker cli already, for example https://hub.docker.com/r/trion/jenkins-docker-client

Comment: How exactly should it be used? Install docker on host, then run helm with the values above and then start this client? Or provide it in podTemplates

Comment: The helm chart specifies a jenkins-agent which is a separate image used to scale the build. The image does not contain the docker cli, so it must be either installed, or an agent image with preinstalled docker must be used.

Comment: I figured I could just add `docker:dind` in a PodTemplate of an agent and it would work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [Kaniko](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko) in your pipeline as it's more secure and following best practices.

an example pipeline:

```
    pipeline {
  agent {
    kubernetes {
      yaml """
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    jenkins: worker
spec:
  containers:
  - name: kaniko
    image: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug
    command: ["/busybox/cat"]
    tty: true
    volumeMounts:
      - name: dockercred
        mountPath: /root/.docker/
  volumes:
  - name: dockercred
    secret:
      secretName: dockercred
"""
    }
  }
  stages {
    stage('Stage 1: Build with Kaniko') {
      steps {
        container('kaniko') {
          sh '/kaniko/executor --context=git://github.com/repository/project.git \
                  --destination=repository/image:tag \
                  --insecure \
                  --skip-tls-verify  \
                  -v=debug'
        }
      }
    }

  }
}
```

you will need to create a docker credential file and mount it as a configmap/secret in order to push the image.